# css is not applying

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp

This is my Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/board/{id}" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String scrumboard(@PathVariable("id") String id) { // if I change    string to key error occurs
    System.out.println(id); //123
    return "html/board";
}
```

This is my HTML code.

```
<a class='scrumboard' href='/board/123'>
```

Problem:

```
<a class='board' href='/board'>
```

If I am using the above statement, I can successfully get the board.jsp page.

```
<a class='board' href='/board/123'>
```

if I pass it with id I can able to retreive the board.jsp page but CSS and JS files are not applicable. In my code, the id is generated dynamically.

Comment: I am using SpringTool Suite in Eclipse and working on Spring legacy project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme-new/" />
```

Put this line in your spring-config.xml file. And change your location in location property.

Comment: I am already having like this.     <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/html/index.jsp" />                                                           It maps to the location were my all my jsp files related to my project are present.  If i replace it with <mvc:resouces it became an error>

Comment: in location set your css folder path.

Comment: location="/WEB-INF/html/index.jsp" to location="/WEB-INF/css/**" or something like that.

Comment: Yeah. Actually i didn't understand resource mapping .So I directly had my  files in web app folder and used it . Now i moved my static files to resources directory and configured.  It was working.